Movie about reincarnated killer
I'm looking for a movie I had watched once in middle school but I can't remember the name. 
All I remember is that a man lost his son and threatened to kill his nephew on his 21st birthday but he dies before the boy turns 21. Then this boy is about to become 21 and two of his friends come and he starts talking about reincarnation and then on the guy's birthday the dead uncle takes the body of the guy's grandma and tries to kill him but then a boy on his bike stops him because he was the reincarnation of the son he lost. 
Only names I can think of is Ben and Johnny. It wasn't a popular movie. It used to be on Netflix.
It was an American film.. it was probably a movie that wasn't popular. 
I remember one of the friends was a girl who had came as a trip and the other friend and this girl had kissed when they were little. I remember near the end it was a grandma who was a sleepwalker but this dead uncle took over her body and had a gun and tried to kill this guy on the night of his birthday. They had made one of those circles around the guy so the 'killer' couldn't get him. 
I think it from 2010.
